# Darken background images with partial transparency using CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using partially transparent CSS sprites (i.e. the object in the image is opaque, the background is transparent). I want to darken the image using CSS or Javascript. I need to make the images change levels of darkness and it's impractical to make a separate image for each level of darkness.

If it wasn't for the transparent background, I could've added a black layer on top of the image and change the opacity of that layer.

Here's basically what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/PXU6j/2/

```
<!-- SO is forcing me to add code -->
<div class=logo>How do I make this darker?</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this can be done. If you were working with vectors or something maybe, but if you can't throw anything on top to darken it I don't see how. I'll be interested to see if someone can come up with something. The only think I can think of is create a solid black version of the image, place on top, use opacity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this:

For each sprite, have **only one** other image that is completely black, but in the same shape as the original. A silhouette, if you will. Then, make a container div, like so:

```
<div class="silhouette">
    <div class="sprite"></div>
</div>
```

Then, you can alter the opacity of the `div.sprite` element and achieve the effect you want. I understand this doesn't truly solve the problem, but I don't know of another way short of using PHP, which doesn't even solve the problem in full either.

Comment: Pretty much what I thought.

Answer (score 12):

Throw a div over it that's black-colored with an alpha channel:

http://jsfiddle.net/PXU6j/3/

Note that I used

```
background-color: #000000;
opacity: 0.7;
```

but you could also use

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
```

Vary opacity and you'll get different shades of dark.

Answer (score 1):

There is no cross-browser compatible solution.

You can either use canvas manipulation with something like [Camanjs](http://camanjs.com/) or [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/), or you can use [css3 filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/filter). Neither of these methods work for non-html5-compatible browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <style>
            #testarea1, #testarea2 {
                position:absolute;
                background-color: #666;
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
            }
            #testarea2 {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>

        <script>

            $(document).ready(function(){

                $("#testarea1").mouseover(function(){
                    $("#testarea2").css("background-color","yellow");
                    $("#testarea1").fadeOut(500);
                    $("#testarea2").fadeIn(1500);
                });

                $("#testarea2").mouseout(function(){

                    $("#testarea1").css("background-color","#666");
                    $("#testarea2").fadeOut(500);
                    $("#testarea1").fadeIn(1500);
                });

            });

        </script>

        <p>Hover to see effect</p>
        <div id="testarea1">displayarea1</div>
        <div id="testarea2">displayarea2</div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: And what's the problem? could you provide some hint? what have you tried? what are you asking?